# Why is .to_string() method needed when opening the path given to the program from its user's input?

Tags: string, rust, user-input

The following code opens a file:

```
use std::fs;
use std::io; 

fn main() {
    
 println!("Give me the absolute path to the file you want to read.");

 let mut to_read = String::new();
 
 io::stdin().read_line(&mut to_read).expect("Failed to read line"); 
    
 to_read = to_read.trim_end().to_string();
 
 let contents = fs::read_to_string(to_read).expect("Something went wrong reading the file");
    
 println!("{}", contents.trim() ); 
    
}
```

From [what I've read](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#tymethod.to_string) about `.to_string()` it converts the given value to a String.
What confuses me is that in my code the given value, i.e. the value assigned to the variable `to_read` is already a String
at the moment of its assignment: `let mut to_read = String::new();`. I discovered through
tinkering,  that the line `to_read = to_read.trim_end().to_string();` is necessary for my code to work, otherwise Rust panics with the message:

> 'Something went wrong reading the file: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }

Why is it so?

Comment: Was building a string with both the file name and the file content the goal ?

Comment: @Denys Yes - I want both the path and the content stored as Strings. The code snippet in question is only a small part of a larger CLI app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trim_end` returns a `&str`: a slice, that is a reference over a portion of the initial string.

So if you do

```
to_read = to_read.trim_end()
```

then you're trying to assign a `&str` to a variable of type `String`.

The solution you took was to build a new `String` from the `&str` with `to_string()`. While this works, it's uselessly expensive as your don't need a String later in `read_to_string`.

A better solution would be to keep the `&str`, in a new variable, which can have the same name:

```
use std::fs;
use std::io; 

fn main() {
    
    println!("Give me the absolute path to the file you want to read.");

    let mut to_read = String::new();
 
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut to_read).expect("Failed to read line"); 
    
    let to_read = to_read.trim_end(); // same name but new variable
 
    let contents = fs::read_to_string(to_read).expect("Something went wrong reading the file");
    
    println!("{}", contents.trim() ); 
    
}
```

Comment: What remains unclear to me is whether I need a String as a parameter for `fs::read_to_string()`. It seems to work fine when its parameter hardcoded, e.g. `fs::read_to_string("/home/jerzy/trackers_best.txt").unwrap()`. **/home/jerzy/trackers_best.txt** here is what compiler describes as **&'static str**, not as **String**, though.

Comment: Wow. I didn't notice something: you use the non version of read_to_string which doesn't take a &mut string as second parameter. My answer is thus completely wrong. Wait a minute I'll edit it

Comment: @JerzyBrzóska I fixed my answer for the right  `read_to_string` function.